# struts2 format string to number without commas and trim trailing zeros

Tags: struts2

I am using Struts2 to format a string to number with trim trailing zeros.

messages.properties :

```
format.number={0,number,#}
```

jsp code :

```
<s:text name="format.number">
    <s:param name="value" value="%{key.policyNumber}" />
</s:text>
```

key.policyNumber is a String, I am getting the error as "**Error 500: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number**"

**UPDATE:** I tried the same code giving a Integer then it works. like

```
<s:text name="format.number">
    <s:param name="value" value="%{key.orderNum}" />
</s:text>
```

action class

```
Map<PolicyObj, CustInfo> mapObj = getDBPolicyDetails();
```

In DB class

```
PolicyObj.setPolicyNumber("0000111111");
```

Comment: Have you considered using JSTL fmt tags for this? I've found it much less a hassle to use JSTL as opposed to Struts 2 formatting the majority of the time.

Comment: Even after using the jstl tag I got almost similar error of "value attribute can not be parsed into java.lang.Number:" Is it because I am using Map to get values.

Comment: Posting some additional action code might be helpful. It sounds to me like you aren't accessing the data correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small change in JSP code. I kind of tricked by converting the string to number.

Here is the code.

```
<s:text name="format.number">
    <s:param name="value" value="key.policyNumber * 1" />
</s:text>
```

**multiplying by 1** is one change I did and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Struts2 uses the [`MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) API to do the formatting and if you look at the [`java.text.NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class, there is no `format` method which takes a String as a parameter.

I don't think you can use formatting in this way.  You'll have to convert the string first before you can format it with Struts2 in this manner.

Comment: Thank you for your response I reached solution in another way.

Comment: Your answer definitely helped me, to reach my solution.